# Change content on dropdown problems

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I want to a dropdown menu that if I select `value1` I get a couple of input fields, and if I select `value2` I get some other input fields. So I found this code online, and I'm trying to adjust it to my needs. Unfortunately it doesn't work, the tables are ALWAYS showing. If I don't work with tables (just plain text) the code works.

**Javascript**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://jsfiddle.net/js/lib/mootools-core-1.4.5-nocompat.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'> 

function showForm(id) {
    document.getElementById('submitForm').style.display = "block";
    if (id == 0) {
        document.getElementById('submitForm').style.display = "none";
    }
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i == id) {
            document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(i).style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Selecteer uw materiaal: </td>
            <td>
            <select id="dropdownMenu" name="dropdownMenu" onchange="javascript: showForm(document.getElementById('dropdownMenu').value);">
                <option value="0">Choose an option</option>
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Other</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
    <div id="1" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td>Aantal videobanden: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="aantalVideo" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Geschatte speelduur (in minuten): </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="duurVideo" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    </div><!-- /1 -->
    <div id="2" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td>Aantal spoelen: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="aantalSpoelen" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Geschatte speelduur (in minuten): </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="duurSpoelen" value="" /></td>
    </tr>       
    </div><!-- /2 -->
    <div id="3" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>Overig</td>
    </tr>
    </div><!-- /3 -->
    <div id="submitForm" style="display: none;">
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input value=" Order aanmaken " type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
    </div><!-- /submitForm -->
    </table>
```

Comment: are you open to using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you give those id's to tr elements rather than creating div's. I tried changing some of the page structure. It worked. I assigned the ids given to the div elements to the tr elements in them and it worked.